# Do applications still print() in release build for C#?

Tags: c#, performance, debugging

I wondered are all the print(), Debug.Log(), Console.WriteLine(), etc... stripped or ignored when being compiled? Does it still affect performance if those functions are still in the release build?

Comment: Often, yes, they do print. But stdout is redirected to a log file or log aggregator. Not positive on the performance impact; I know when printing to a terminal it can have horrendous performance implications but maybe if it's directed elsewhere it might not be as bad. Good question. N.B. I'm thinking in the context of a server. For client-side apps it's sometimes better to strip.

Comment: It depends. Ask a question about a specific programming language, environment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy question: yes, release builds of real life applications do print (log) data. For various reasons: debugging (yes, you do debug the release builds), auditing, etc.

Your second question is also easy - yes, it negatively affects the performance. In time-critical code, the asynchronous logging is often used, where you queue your data and it gets written at some later point.